# Value of $f_x g_x+ f_y g_y + f_z g_z$ when $f$ and $g$ are harmonic

Tags: harmonic-functions

Let $f$ and $g$ be distinct real-valued  harmonic functions, which not merely differ by a constant or are not merely multiples of each other. Also, assume that the first order partial derivatives of the two functions do not vanish identically. Is it true that in such a case the expression $f_xg_x+f_yg_y+f_zg_z$ will attain positive as well as negative values?

Comment: We have
$$\nabla^2 (fg) = \sum_{i} (fg)_{x_i,x_i} = \sum_{i} \left(f_{x_i,x_i}g + fg_{x_i,x_i} 2 f_{x_i} g_{x_i}\right) = g \nabla^2 f + f \nabla^2 g + 2 (\vec{\nabla} f) \cdot (\vec{\nabla} g)$$
Since $f,g$ are harmonic, we have
$$\nabla^2 (fg) = 2 (\vec{\nabla} f) \cdot (\vec{\nabla} g)$$

Comment: @Leg Thanks for pointing that out. But I still cannot see how $\Delta (fg)$  cannot be always $\ge 0$ or always $\le 0$.

Comment: It depends on the chosen domain. If your expression is $>0$ at some point it will be strictly positive in a full neighborhood of this point.